# Debug-id in android

Tags: braintree-sandbox

Hey I am working on an android project and I am new in android.I am implementing someones code to add paypal Braintree payment method  while debugging,I am getting
D/****MAGNES DEBUGGING MESSAGE****: DeviceInfoRequest returned PayPal-Debug-Id: 71171000f8a07 on locat. What is it? and how it will be fix.

Comment: did u get answer for this one?

Comment: Do any updates getting the same?